# Como evitar el error.code 1006 en WebSocket

Tags: java, javascript, websocket

Del lado cliente, tengo configurado websocket con javascript.
Del lado servidor, tengo configurado websocket con java.

La configuración es bastante sencilla y funciona correctamente. Una vez al día, de forma aleatoria, los clientes (javascript) comienzan a dar el código de error 1006 y se desconectan.
Por el momento, lo que hice fue detectar el error 1006 y volver a conectar el websocket al servidor de la siguiente forma:

```
socket.onclose = function (msg) {
  if (msg.code == "1006") {
    setTimeout(function () {
      conectar(); => funcion que reconecta el websocket
    }, 1000)
  }
};
```

Lo que quiero evitar justamente es el error 1006, ya que desconecta a todos los clientes al mismo tiempo. Buscando un poco, encuentro lo siguiente:

```
1006

  1006 is a reserved value and MUST NOT be set as a status code in a
  Close control frame by an endpoint.  It is designated for use in
  applications expecting a status code to indicate that the
  connection was closed abnormally, e.g., without sending or
  receiving a Close control frame.
```

Aun buscando un poco mas:

```
Close Code 1006 is a special code that means the connection was closed
abnormally (locally) by the browser implementation.

If your browser client reports close code 1006, then you should be 
looking at the websocket.onerror(evt) event for details.

However, Chrome will rarely report any close code 1006 reasons to the    
javascript side. This is likely due to client security rules in the 
WebSocket spec to prevent abusing websocket. (such as using it to scan 
for open ports on a destination server, or for generating lots of 
connections for a denial-of-service attack).
```

Si bien me queda claro que el error viene por la falta de envío o recepción de un frame de control, no me queda claro como solucionar y si hay posibilidad de hacerlo.

Alguien tuvo algún problema similar y lo resolvió correctamente?

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema. Estaba escribiendo una pregunta similar ahora mismo. ¿Estás usando algún tutorial en concreto?

Comment: No, no estoy utilizando ningún tutorial. Estas haciendo algún PING/PONG entre cliente / servidor? Yo lo estoy haciendo cada 5 minutos, puede que venga por ahí el problema. Ahora lo reduje a 20 segundos.

Comment: Alguna idea gente? Gracias!

Comment: Pudiera ser un problema de sincronización, te recomiendo usar **clearTimeout** antes de asignar nuevamente un **setTimeout**, Saludos.

Comment: Pregunta: ¿En algún momento a la hora de conectar los sockets ustedes setean el puerto?

Comment: Lamento que haya pasado tanto tiempo pero la respuesta es simple: En mi caso tenía problemas con el proxy. El servidor Proxy de la empresa no estaba funcionando como debería y se reiniciaba. Las conexiones WebSocket pasaban por el proxy y por ende, se cerraban cada vez que el proxy se reiniciaba. Una cosa mas, el código 1006 no es UN ERROR. Es un código que simplemente indica que la conexión se cerró inesperadamente.